# How do I paginate through a ViewModel in MVC CORE?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In the MVC CORE demo from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page the Contoso university sample program uses a model on the paginating example page

```
var students = from s in _context.Students
                           select s;
return View(await PaginatedList<Student>.CreateAsync(students.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
```

while the viewmodel gets passed back as a complete entity like this

```
var viewModel = new InstructorIndexData();
viewModel.Instructors = await _context.Instructors
.Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
.Include(i => i.CourseAssignments)
.ThenInclude(i => i.Course)
.ThenInclude(i => i.Department)
.OrderBy(i => i.LastName)
.ToListAsync();

return View(viewModel);
```

**How do I paginate through the returned records of a viewmodel.**

I've tried passing the viewmodel into the PaginatedList like this.

```
return View(await PaginatedList<InstructorIndexData>.CreateAsync(viewModel.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
```

which has the error

```
Error   CS1061  'InstructorIndexData' does not contain a definition for 'AsNoTracking' and no extension method 'AsNoTracking' accepting a first argument of type 'InstructorIndexData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**Edit**
The ViewModel is

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Models.SchoolViewModels
{
    public class InstructorIndexData
    {
        public IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

changing the IEnumerable to IQueryable causes the following

```
    var viewModel = new InstructorIndexData();
    viewModel.Instructors = await _context.Instructors
          .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
          .Include(i => i.CourseAssignments)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.Course)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Department)
          .OrderBy(i => i.LastName)
          .ToListAsync();
```

to produce the error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Instructor>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Instructor>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this?  I am battling a very similar issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
AsNoTracking()
```

is an Extension Method defnied in the DbExtension assembly.
The property "Instructors" must be of a type that implements "IQueryable" to enable this extension method.

Also, in your provided code sample

```cs
return View(await PaginatedList<InstructorIndexData>.CreateAsync(viewModel.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
```

You are using the extension method over the viewModel itself and not the property "Instructors"

Comment: Which extension method do you mean?

Comment: The "AsNoTracking" requires the subject of the method (the instance) to be an implementation of "IQueryable" view model is to my assumption not an implementation of IQueryable.
But "Instructors" is

Comment: Do you mean changing the viewmodel's reference to the model as in the edit above from IEnumerable to IQueryable?

Comment: No, that is not what i've said.
I proposed to call "AsNoTracking" on the "Instructors" property and not on the ViewModel itself.
this:
return View(await PaginatedList<InstructorIndexData>.CreateAsync(viewModel.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
will be this:
return View(await PaginatedList<InstructorData>.CreateAsync(viewModel.Instructors.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));

Comment: Using that and leaving the viewmodel as ` public IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }` causes the error `IEnumerable<Instructor> does not contain a definition for AsNoTracking`

Changing the viewmodel to         `public IQueryable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }` causes a lot of errors about implicitly converting Lists to IQeuryables and regarding that line specifically. `cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Instructor>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ContosoUniversity.Models.SchoolViewModels.InstructorIndexData>'`

Comment: Use more lower level abstraction, instead of IEnumerable use IList

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150624/discussion-between-h-bloch-and-glyn).